# Cannot access https on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following is my `base_url of` **config.php** in my project.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/';
```

But my website always go to `http://www.mywebsite.com` unless the user implicitly write https in browser url.

What is the problem?

Why codeigniter goes to url that define in config.php ?

Comment: I'm not sure how CodeIgniter handles this, but redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS could be (and should be) performed by the webserver. So which webserver are you using?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil I do not know what the server is. I am using hostgator hosting. And how can I know the webserver?

Comment: Okay, look at [this site](http://www.softwarehtec.com/redirect-https-http-http-https-hostgator-hosting/) - it sums up how to set up HTTP to HTTPS redirection on a HostGator webhosting.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS :- Full name is (hyper text transfer protocol secure). It’s a extended or you can say secure version of the HTTP(hyper text transfer protocol). If you have https enabled on your server you will get a lock icon in address bar of browser.
For encryption of data it’s used SSL(secure sockets layer) certificates to install on your server. Most uses of https to securely transmit data with ssl.
So most of sites need ssl or https url. we can easily manage redirection to https url in codeigniter using hooks. it’s a one more good feature of CI. We need to create some lines of code to get ssl url or redirect to https url in codeigniter. Default codeigniter not have this type of functionality so we need to force redirect to ssl url. below we will see how to use ssl redirect with codeigniter.

1.Config changes :- `application/config/config.php` and enable or set hooks to true.

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

2.create a new file named hooks.php in `application/config/hooks.php` and add below code in `hooks.php`.

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(

                                'function' => 'redirect_ssl',

                                'filename' => 'ssl.php',

                                'filepath' => 'hooks'

                                );
```

3.Now create a new directory with named `hooks` under application directory and then create new file named `ssl.php` in `application/hooks/ssl.php`
and add below code to `ssl.php`.

```
function redirect_ssl() {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();

    $exclude =  array('client');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.

    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {

      // redirecting to ssl.

      $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);

      if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());

    } 

    else {

      // redirecting with no ssl.

      $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);

      if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());

    }

}
```

Now check your site you will get https in url. redirect to https url in codeigniter using `hooks` is a good method rather than `htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.htaccess` file in the root directory that is used to allow "pretty URLs", you can add some commands that will force a redirect the "https" protocol.

After the line

```
RewriteEngine on
```

at these lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

The rest of the commands remain the same.

Leave your setting of `$config['base_url']` as you show in the question. No other code changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use HOOKS as it is simpler than .htaccess.
first change base url in ***

> application/config/config.php

---

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.mywebsite.com';
```

Inside

> application/config/hooks.php

write this code as:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
                                'function' => 'redirect_ssl',
                                'filename' => 'ssl.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

Now make a file name as **ssl.php** inside

> application/hooks/

and paste the below code

```
<?php
function redirect_ssl() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $exclude =  array('');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
      // redirecting to ssl.
      $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
      if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    } 
    else {
      // redirecting with no ssl.
      $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
      if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
?>
```

Now it should work like charm as I have used the same method and found as the easiest one